# Change all columns except the 1st to dollar format

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
A    B    C    D     E      F      G
AA   1    2    3     4      5      6
BB   3    2    1     9     23    2.6
CC   2    5    1   1.9    2.5   2.99
```

How do I change this dataframe to have all the columns converted to a dollar format using the scales package? For a single column I can just do this:

```
library(scales)
df$B<-dollar(df$B)
```

How do I do this for all the columns except the first one without writing this over and over again for each column?

Comment: df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], dollar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this with `lapply`

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], dollar)
df
#   A  B  C  D     E      F     G
#1 AA $1 $2 $3 $4.00  $5.00 $6.00
#2 BB $3 $2 $1 $9.00 $23.00 $2.60
#3 CC $2 $5 $1 $1.90  $2.50 $2.99
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(B:G), dollar)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
df[,2:ncol(df)] = dollar(as.matrix(df[,2:ncol(df)]))
df
#   A     B     C     D     E      F     G
#1 AA $1.00 $2.00 $3.00 $4.00  $5.00 $6.00
#2 BB $3.00 $2.00 $1.00 $9.00 $23.00 $2.60
#3 CC $2.00 $5.00 $1.00 $1.90  $2.50 $2.99
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[, 2:ncol(df)] = apply(df[, 2:ncol(df)], 2, function(x) dollar(x))
```

OR

```
df[,2:ncol(df)] = dollar(as.matrix(df[,2:ncol(df)]))
```